# Sql CURDATE() not working for next month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I have a query that returns the count of entries based on CURDATE(), it works for any dat in this month (April) but does not work for next month (May).

**This Works as Date is in April**

```
SELECT COUNT(Machine) FROM production 
WHERE Status = 'Confirmed'  
AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(production.Required)) = CURDATE()
```

**This does not work as in May**

```
SELECT COUNT(Machine) FROM production 
WHERE Status = 'Confirmed'  
AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(production.Required)) = CURDATE()+3
```

Comment: `CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 3 DAY`

Comment: `CURDATE()+3` just adds 3 to the date as a number, so you end up with 20180431

Answer (score 2):

Your query is better written as:

```
WHERE Status = 'Confirmed' AND 
      production.Required >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() + interval 3 day) AND
      production.Required < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() + interval 4 day)
```

Although this seems more complicated, it allows the optimize to use an index if an appropriate one is available (in this case, the best index would seem to be `(status, Required)`.  Functions on columns generally prevent indexes and other optimizations.

Comment: I ended up converting both sides of the condition with UNIX_TIMESTAMP then it worked.

Comment: @Dr.AaronDishno .  . That prevents the use of an index.  There is a reason why the query is written this way.